# Using a dictionary outside of the void its created in

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, filedialog

Im unsure about how i can use a dictionary i create when i click a button which mean that i cannot reference to it from within another function. This is probably very basic, but i simply cannot remember how this is done.

This is the button that opens up a file dialog, which then reads each line inside the file, and stores the contents inside the dictionary:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Mod Pack Configuration file|*.mcf";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Load Mod Pack Configuration File";
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> loadfile =
        File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
            .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
            .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Then afterwards i load a function, that places the loaded files, strings inside different controls within the form. However the below code doesnt work as "loaddfile" is not found:

```
public void getDefaultSettings()
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.modsDestDropDown != "") 
    {
        modsDestDropDown.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(loadfile['modsDestDropDown']);
    }
}
```

I could ofcourse write the function inside the button1 click event instead, but since i use this function across the program in other places, it would then give me some trouble later

Comment: Can you just make the dictionary global?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your dictionary in the `class level`, **outside** of your methods like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> loadfile;
```

Then just initialize it in your method:

```
loadfile = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
               .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
               .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

loadFile is currently a local variable only available in the scope of button1_Click. If you want it available in more than one method you should make it a field on your class.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> loadfile;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Mod Pack Configuration file|*.mcf";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Load Mod Pack Configuration File";
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
        loadfile =
        File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
            .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
            .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);
    }
}
```